# count number of times the name of each US state is mentioned in a string column- creating 51 new columns for all the states

Tags: r

I have a column that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("travel_history" = c("Jane Doe travelled to indiana, stayed there for 1 year, then went to Austin, Texas for a week, then New York and then back to Indiana", "John was in Colombus, Ohio, then went to alabama, then Indiana, and then went to California. he visited Alabama again, but eventually settled in California"))
```

I want to create 51 new columns, each for the number of times each US state is mentioned in travel_history. so for the example above:

```
df$Alabama <- c(0,2)
df$Indiana <- c(2,1)
df$Texas <- c(1,0)
df$Ohio <-(0,1)
df$Oregon <-(0,0)
```

and so on.

I know that I can do this manually like this:

```
df$Alabama <- str_count(df$travel_history, "Alabama")
```

but I was wondering if there's a more efficient solution that doesn't require me manually creating 51 columns for each data frame I am dealing with; maybe using a map package with state names?

I thought of creating a function that takes a df and creates a new global df by binding the 51 columns to it but then I guess I'd have to use assign and paste and I  cannot figure out how to create global variables with assign and paste functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could loop over the 'state.name' and apply `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
df[state.name] <-  lapply(tolower(state.name), 
         function(x) str_count(tolower(df$travel_history), x))
```

EDIT: Based on @ChuckP comments

Or may be use the `ignore_case`

```
df[state.name] <- lapply(state.name, function(x) str_count(df$travel_history, regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

---

Or using `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfc(state.name, ~ df %>% 
    transmute(!! .x := str_count(travel_history, 
               regex(.x, ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .)
travel_history
#1                       Jane Doe travelled to indiana, stayed there for 1 year, then went to Austin, Texas for a week, then New York and then back to Indiana
#2 John was in Colombus, Ohio, then went to alabama, then Indiana, and then went to California. he visited Alabama again, but eventually settled in California
#  Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut Delaware Florida Georgia Hawaii Idaho Illinois Indiana Iowa Kansas Kentucky
#1       0      0       0        0          0        0           0        0       0       0      0     0        0       2    0      0        0
#2       2      0       0        0          2        0           0        0       0       0      0     0        0       1    0      0        0
#  Louisiana Maine Maryland Massachusetts Michigan Minnesota Mississippi Missouri Montana Nebraska Nevada New Hampshire New Jersey New Mexico New York
#1         0     0        0             0        0         0           0        0       0        0      0             0          0          0        1
#2         0     0        0             0        0         0           0        0       0        0      0             0          0          0        0
#  North Carolina North Dakota Ohio Oklahoma Oregon Pennsylvania Rhode Island South Carolina South Dakota Tennessee Texas Utah Vermont Virginia
#1              0            0    0        0      0            0            0              0            0         0     1    0       0        0
#2              0            0    1        0      0            0            0              0            0         0     0    0       0        0
#  Washington West Virginia Wisconsin Wyoming
#1          0             0         0       0
#2          0             0         0       0
```

Comment: Probably want to add a `tolower` in there @akrun as in `df[state.name] <- lapply(tolower(state.name), function(x) str_count(tolower(df$travel_history), x))` very plausible even in the example data to see case issues

Comment: @ChuckP The state.name gives `state.name#
 [1] "Alabama" ..`. I was thinking the OP wanted the case to be camel case

Comment: @ChuckP thanks, you are right.  I was thinking that the OP had a typo

Comment: In the example data you don't catch for example Indiana twice in the first row because there is an entry properly capitalized and one not